# Internal Server Error when integrating chatbot using Webchat in SAP Commerce Cloud

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, sap-conversational-ai

I have installed SAP Commerce 1905. I also created my own chatbot using SAP Conversational AI which i am integrating to B2C Electronic Storefront using webchat.

I can see a nice chatbot in my B2C Electronic Storefront but as soon as i am sending "Hi" to my chatbot, i am getting "Internal Server Error" in console and in chatbot "Couldn’t send this message Try again"

I am not able to understand whats happening wrong.

[image]

**Network Error -**

[image]

[image]

**Console Error -**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

could you please try to hit the same request via postman let see if it's responding or not.